# Get notified when an NSQD node is not available

Tags: go, message-queue, nsq

NSQ provides an endpoint to get all `nsqd` nodes available via `nsqdlookupd` (https://nsq.io/components/nsqlookupd.html#get-nodes):

> GET /nodes - Anchor link for: get nodes
> Returns a list of all known nsqd

that means that if I want to know whether a node is up I'll need to hit this endpoint, but in order to keep my list of nodes up to date I'd need to hit this endpoint quite often which worries me.

Is there a way to subscribe to some event which indicates when a node was dropped/added?